# Improving efficiency of Sieve of Eratosthenes code in java

Tags: java, performance, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I've worked upon a code for [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) in Java, but I face a few time and space efficiency issues. 
Here's the code :

```
import java.util.*;

class EratosthenesSeive
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        ArrayList<Long> myPrimeList = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Long> myTempPrimeList = new ArrayList<Long>();
        ArrayList<Boolean> isPrimeNumber = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        int index = 0;

        long ul = 1500l;
        long ll = 2;

        do
        {
            myTempPrimeList.add(ll);
            isPrimeNumber.add(true);
            ll++;
        }while( ll != (ul+1));

        for(long i : myTempPrimeList)
        {
            if(isPrimeNumber.get(index))
            {
                myPrimeList.add(i);
                for(long j = i ; j*i <= ul; j++)
                {
                    isPrimeNumber.set(myTempPrimeList.indexOf(j*i),false);
                }
            }
            index++;
        }

        System.out.println(myPrimeList);
    }
}
```

It seems to be working fine for input upto 10^3, at 10^4 it simply hangs and at 10^5 and above I get [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html).
And the code seems to be working alright, but I would like to fasten it up a bit more. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible optimization would be replacing the ArrayLists with arrays of primitive types, given that you know beforehand the size of the arrays needed. This will have the effect of preventing all the unnecessary boxing/unboxing of values currently present in your code.

Also, be aware that you don't have to store even numbers in the array, only odd numbers - doing so will reduce the memory requirements *and* processing time by half.

For solving the OutOfMemoryError you can fiddle with the JVM's configuration parameters at startup, making available more heap space for the application.

Answer (score 4):

You are boxing/unboxing a *ton* in that code. You may want to try replacing the `ArrayList<>`s with straight arrays of the primitive type.

Comment: Had to select the other answer as the correct one because it even suggested me about how to make more heap space available. :-)

Comment: No worries - it's all about getting the problem fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Double the speed by not working with even numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing a lot more work than it needs to. You just need a single array of booleans, two loops to mark the non-prime numbers and another loop to print the index numbers of the primes. Like this:

```
public void printPrimes(int max) {

    // declare a single array of booleans
    boolean[] primeFlags = new boolean[max + 1];

    // double loop sieve-style and mark non-primes as true
    for (int m = 2; m <= (int)Math.sqrt(max); m++) 
        for (int k = m*m; k <= max; k += m) primeFlags[k] = true;

    // loop over bool array and print indexes with false values 
    // which will be the prime numbers
    for (int m = 2; m <= max; m++)
        if (!primeFlags[m]) System.out.print(m + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

//Sieve Of Erastothenes

public class SieveOfErastothenes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a range n : ");
        int n = sc.nextInt();

        boolean ar[] = new boolean[n+1];
        for (int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        ar[i] = true;

        for(int i = 2;i*i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(ar[i])
            {
                for(int j=i;i*j<=n;j++)
                    ar[i*j]=false;
            }
        }

        for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
        {
            if(ar[i])
                System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        sc.close();

    }

}

/*This code is contributed by Asish Samantaray*/
```